# Secondary Y-axis display data differs from actual data

Tags: highcharts

I am a Highcharts beginner currently working with legacy code. The project displays two line graphs in the same space, each with their own y-axis, with data points over a 24 hour period. One varies wildly between 1400 and 1600 and the other is either a 0 or a 1 over time.

For some reason, when we render the 1400 graph first and then the 0/1 graph, the 0/1 graph averages to 0.5 as soon as its value would have been a 1, then remains as 0.5 even when its value would have been a 0. Example:
[image]
When only the 0/1 graph is displayed or when it is the primary axis, there are no problems. Example:
[image]

Looking at related questions, we do have alignTicks set to false, a common solution. Please see screenshots for this behavior. Any suggestions on where the problem might be?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle that recreates the problem?  We can't help you solve it without any code.

Comment: I figured that would be the case. I will be creating one soon, as that would be very helpful.

Comment: is this Highcharts or Highstock? Make sure that `dataGrouping` is not enabled: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.dataGrouping